# CSS class:hover select all other elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I can't find how to do this online, how do I go about selecting any elements within a element and apply styles to them. For example:

HTML:

```
<div class="cont">
   <div class="txt">Hello World!</div>
   <img src="img1.jpg">
   <img src="img2.jpg">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.txt:hover + img {
   display:none;
}
```

I want that class style to hide ALL images next to it. It only hides ONE image at the moment though...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to hide *all* succeeding image elements, use the [general sibling combinator, `~`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#general-sibling-combinators).

```
.txt:hover ~ img {
   display:none;
}
```

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z4JfV/)

You were using the [adjacent sibling combinator, `+`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#adjacent-sibling-combinators), which will only hide the adjacent element.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I did find a website ages ago that shows these kind of neat tricks, but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: @MartynLeeBall This is a pretty good reference: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/

Comment: Thanks! That's the exact website I had found ages ago and couldn't find again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in two ways; With CSS-only, and with jQuery:

**CSS-way:**

```
.txt:hover ~ img {
   display:none;
}
```

**jQuery-way:**

```
$(function() {

   $('.txt').hover(function() {
      $('img').toggle();
   });

});
```

Comment: You could do this in a myriad of ways, but it would be incredibly messy to list them all, especially if they don't fit the question at hand.